# Обращение к сторонней MYSQL-базе

Tags: python, mysql

Есть самописный скрипт, который парсит ники с одной хмл-странички. Все, что мне нужно, это по каждому из ников сделать запрос в стороннюю mysql-базу. В строке базы хранится число, нужно сделать к этому числу +1. Вот собственно и все. Как мне это реализовать? Python 3.2.

Answer (score 1):

Сложно сказать что используется для python 3 в качестве адаптера, но быстрый поиск указал на это: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/oursql/0.9.2

А здесь how-to: http://packages.python.org/oursql/tutorial.html

Comment: Не считаю это за ошибку, но сам неоднократно делал ее, почитайте пожалуйста статью в блоге [Внешние зависимости](http://blog.hashcode.ru/2011/03/blog-post_12.html). Не повторяйте моих ошибок.

Comment: не поддерживает этот модуль третий питон...